# How to change the edit widget for fields in a layer with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is possible change the edit widget with PyQGIS?

I have made an extension that loads a PostGIS layer and I want to edit the date fields with the date widget by default without any change in the settings of layer ( "layer properties dialog").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the method `setEditorWidgetV2()` from `QgsVectorLayer`.

To set the edit widget of a field to `DateTime`, do this:

```
vLayer.setEditorWidgetV2( fieldIndex, 'DateTime' )
```

Parameters can be set via a dictionary of key-values, like this:

```
vLayer.setEditorWidgetV2Config( fieldIndex, {'display_format': 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'allow_null': False, 'field_format': 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'calendar_popup': True})
```

[image]

You can find a description of the available options at the [`QgsDateTimeEditWrapper` documentation](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsDateTimeEditWrapper.html#details).

A list of available widgets can be found [here](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a05a33f4d4f9953571f680f6b18589559).

---

On the other hand, if you want all your Date fields to have the DateTime edit widget, you could do something like this:

```
fields = vLayer.dataProvider().fields()
dateFields = []
# Get indices of date fields
for field in fields: 
    if field.typeName() == 'Date':
        dateFields.append( vLayer.fieldNameIndex(field.name()) )

# Set the DateTime editor widget for date fields
for dateField in dateFields:
    vLayer.setEditorWidgetV2( dateField, 'DateTime' )
```

Comment: Is possible to initiate the calendar on Monday? I know that QCalendarWidget has this option, but I don't know if it is possible to change it this way.

Comment: Probably not, at least I couldn't find such option.